# Detect Default Storage is SD card or phone Internal Memory in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, sd-card, android-external-storage

Can we detect, Default Storage is SD card or Phone memory in Android Studio?

Actually, I am making simple cameraApp, All the pictures taken are saved into my Phone's External Storage, but in API 19 and lower, the pictures are saving in my galley and also in Phone's Gallery in which Primary Storage is SD card but I don't want them to save in Gallery

So I want to make 3 conditions:

1. if there is SD card present
2. If API is 19 or lower than 19
3. If Default storage is SD card

I can do first 2 things programmatically, but don't know how to do the third one programmatically

Can we detect, Default Storage is SD card or Phone memory in android studio programmatically?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So you need to store the pictures in SD card instead of phones memory?

Comment: @SafanMomin no in phones memory.. But i want to detect if SD card is Primary storage is not, because if it is not selected as primary Memory then it is working fine

Comment: have you found any solution?